# Google analytics in drupal site: events dont work

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-analytics

I have a drupal 6 site with google analytics module. All the tracking is set up properly except when i try to track a specific event, using this code:

```
<a href="xxxx/xxxx" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Main Clicks', 'title', ' nid 4204']);">xxxxxxx</a>
```

i looked in this old link:
http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/drupal-google-analytics-and-event-tracking
but i checked and my GA code is at the head